# SQL table select

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables:

- `Patients` where I have patient_ID as primary key and other details.
- `Patients_Treatments` where I have patient_ID from Patients as foreign key, treatment_code, and other columns.

I am requested to find all the patient's treatment codes that have the same treatment_code as patient whose id is 999.

I'm sitting for two days trying to find a solution and I just can't manage to think of something. It seems simple but I just can't find a solution.

**Example:**

[image]

The expected output are the details (Details means first name, last name, and patient ID) of: Tal Shalom Dan Shabtay Elad Gigi

Comment: Please explain what *regular SQL* is.  Is this SQL Server?  Oracle?  Something else?

Comment: Can you add sample table data  and expected result to your question? And show us your current query attempt, and tell us what's wrong with it? (School assignment?)

Comment: please post the some sample data then only we can give solution that you can implement in your requirement

Comment: Okay I'll add a screen shot:

Comment: http://imgur.com/4zE2hgc

Comment: The expected output are the details (Details means first name, last name, and patient ID of:
Tal Shalom
Dan Shabtay
Elad Gigi
Please ignore the example in the original post I got confused myself, this one is correct though.

Comment: And regular SQL is SQL Server (SQL Server Management Studio something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the `Treatment_Code` and `Patient` information for the patients that share a `Treatment_Code` belonging to `Patient_Id: 999`, this should get you those results:

```
Select  T.Treatment_Code, P.First_Name, P.Last_Name, P.Patient_Id
From    Patients_Treatments T
Join    Patients            P   On  P.Patient_Id = T.Patient_Id
Where   T.Patient_Id In
(
    Select  T1.Patient_Id
    From    Patients_Treatments T
    Join    Patients_Treatments T1  On  T1.Treatment_Code = T.Treatment_Code
                                    And T1.Patient_ID <> T.Patient_Id
    Where   T.Patient_Id = 999
)
```